# Input box and checkbox’s heights are different

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made a login box using Bootstrap 3.0.3. On the second line, the password input box’s and check box”s (labelled `Auth`) heights are different. On mobile, the difference is even more noticeable.

How can I make their heights match?

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/98861)

```
<form name="fhead" method="post" onsubmit="return fhead_submit(this);" autocomplete="off" role="form" class="form-inline">
<div id="outlogin_box" name="outlogin_box">
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="<?=$outlogin_url?>">
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="mb_id" maxlength="20" itemname="id" placeholder="login id">
<div class="input-group"><!-- needs height alignment -->
    <input type="password" class="form-control input-sm" name="mb_password" id="outlogin_mb_password" maxlength="20" itemname="password" placeholder="password">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="auto_login" title="Remember me" value="1" onclick="if (this.checked) { if (confirm('자동로그인을 사용하시면 다음부터 회원아이디와 패스워드를 입력하실 필요가 없습니다.\n\n\공공장소에서는 개인정보가 유출될 수 있으니 사용을 자제하여 주십시오.\n\n자동로그인을 사용하시겠습니까?')) { this.checked = true; } else { this.checked = false; } }">
        Auto
        </label>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-group-justified" >Login</button>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" title="Register" href="<?=$g4[bbs_path]?>/register.php">Register</a>
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" title="회원 id, password 찾기" href="javascript:win_password_lost();">아이디찾기</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
<input class="form-control input-sm" name="mb_password" ...
```

to

```
<input class="form-control" name="mb_password" ...
```

http://www.bootply.com/98872

You have modified the height of the input by adding a class "input-sm".

Comment: Fang // Great. I forgot input-sm class tag.

Answer (score 3):

**Try this very simple:**

```
input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1px;
  }
  input[type=radio] {
    bottom: 2px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set fixed width and height values for HTML textboxes/checkboxes in CSS by doing the following...

```
input[type="text"] {
    width: 10%;
    height:3%;
}
input[type="password"] {
    width: 10%;
    height:3%;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
    height:2%;
}
```

You can also set them using px instead of percentages.
Hopefully setting a fixed height and width should resolve your conflicting size problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try **overriding bootstrap CSS** with this:

```
.input-group-addon .checkbox {
    margin: 8px 5px 0 !important;
}

.input-group-addon {
    padding:0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your css of checkbox class display which is display : inline-block to display: inline and the try it

.form-inline .radio,.form-inline .checkbox{display:inline-block;padding-left:0;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0}

to

.form-inline .radio,.form-inline .checkbox{display:inline;padding-left:0;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0}

in bootstrap.min.css